# Sending GET from PHP parameter to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

My coding isn't working. Please anyone could tell me why?
Here's the code:

AJAX code:

```
function sale(sale_code,sale_quantity) {
        if (sale_code.length == 0 || sale_quantity == 0) {
            alert("Product's code & quantity are required!");
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "sl.php?sdoc_no=<?= $sdoc_no ?>&sdoc_date=<?= $sdoc_date ?>&sale_code=" + sale_code + "&sale_quantity=" + sale_quantity, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    }
```

HTML & PHP:

```
<?php $qitem = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE stock_type = 'product'");
while($ritem = mysqli_fetch_array($qitem)){ ?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="button" onclick="sale(<?= $ritem['stock_code'] ?>, 1)"><?= $ritem["stock_name"] ?><br />
        <small>RM <?= number_format($ritem["stock_sprice"], 2) ?></small>
    </button>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

sl.php file is working and returning data if i'm put it manually. And take note that I'm using bootstrap tab for this button.

Comment: You say "isn't working". What happens? Do you get any error message in the console?

Comment: Nope. Its all good before i put into bootstrap tab/pills menu. Is it bootstrap problem? Or my code? I checked all my code and it seems no error.

Comment: What does `$ritem['stock_code']` contain? Text or just numbers?

Comment: Its a string. Maybe barcode int, or may there is varchar

Comment: Ah..  try this: `sale('<?= $ritem['stock_code'] ?>', 1)`. (Add `'`-signs around the parameter, which is needed for strings). You should also uri encode your parameters before adding them as querystring, For js: [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) and for PHP: [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Wow. It works! Tq. Just before, i put that barcode in an input field, so its work because it call stock_code.value as a varible. Now i see, its a string.. :) tq.

Comment: I can add it as an answer so you can check the question as closed. :)

Comment: Okay. Thats what i am waiting for. Really appreciate it with thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have quotes around string parameters in js:

Change:

```
sale(<?= $ritem['stock_code'] ?>, 1)
```

to:

```
sale('<?= $ritem['stock_code'] ?>', 1)
```

Then you should uri encode your parameters before you use them as url-parameters.

For JS, use [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) and for PHP, use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php);

Answer (score 1):

**HOW COULDN'T I SEE IT...**

You have this wrong:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "sl.php?sdoc_no=<?= $sdoc_no ?>&sdoc_date=<?= $sdoc_date ?>&sale_code=" + sale_code + "&sale_quantity=" + sale_quantity, true);
```

You cannot use PHP in JavaScript... so you have this wrong:

```
sl.php?sdoc_no=<?= $sdoc_no ?>&sdoc_date=<?= $sdoc_date ?>&sale_code=" + sale_code + "&sale_quantity=" + sale_quantity
```

This `<?= $sdoc_no ?>` and `<?= $sdoc_date ?>` is not valid JS code...

Comment: I am putting < php instead of <?php becasue this forum text editor doesn't support to much php tag. 
Btw, it's still not working.

Comment: I know about the php tag. What i am gonna say is, the code isnt working.

Comment: I edit the php tag. The original file is using the correct tag. Only for this forum i editted it. Do you get it? The problem is, even using the correct tag, still doesn

Comment: Look at my new answer

Comment: @MrHery - Is your javascript inline js in a .php-file (using `<script>`-tags) or is it in a separate .js-file?

Comment: Yep it is. So it does support php tag in javascript right?

Comment: @MrHery - it is what? I gave you two alternatives? :)

Comment: Its a php file. Not js.

Comment: Ok, @P0lT10n - Then he can have PHP-code in the JS.

Comment: Please, put the entire file on question